# Javascript - getAttribute() works for the first element only

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my HTML:

```
<div class="tool-top">
    <ul>
        <li><a role="button" id="button" value="bold"><i class="fas fa-bold"></i></a></li>
        <li><a role="button" id="button" value="italic"><i class="fas fa-italic"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

this is my JS:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(){
    
        var a = this.getAttribute('value');
        console.log(a);
    }
}
```

I get 'bold' when clicking the first button but nothing in the second

I looked on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699463/how-to-undo-selected-highlighted-text-when-click-on-button-with-codemirror?fbclid=IwAR0mOWm6SEjQr0C8n1Dhmr2U-iuqGxI7-N0NdcYU3MaShpEHmIFaSM8UZuo) page, but it wrote with Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

An ID should always be unique. You have two elements with the same ID here, use a class instead:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('button');

  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].onclick = function() {
      var a = this.getAttribute('value');
      console.log(a);
    };
  }
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="tool-top">
  <ul>
    <li><a role="button" class="button" value="bold"><i class="fas fa-bold"></i></a></li>
    <li><a role="button" class="button" value="italic"><i class="fas fa-italic"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you have jQuery *(you added the tag to your question)*, you can do this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    var a = this.getAttribute('value');
    console.log(a);
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="tool-top">
  <ul>
    <li><a role="button" class="button" value="bold"><i class="fas fa-bold"></i></a></li>
    <li><a role="button" class="button" value="italic"><i class="fas fa-italic"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ok! thanks for your help